# Scroll content area only with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a small project whose front-end is built with the latest version of Bootstrap. I have my sections of the homepage, but I am stuck on making them behave the way I want.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid max-height">
        <div class="row max-height">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 site-nav">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="brand">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x320" class="img-responsive" alt="logo" />
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- .brand -->
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem libero, vulputate vel tellus eu, suscipit facilisis metus. Nulla tempus cursus elit, eget pellentesque risus euismod ut. Fusce sed sodales mauris. In velit arcu, blandit sed tempor vitae, feugiat eu erat. Phasellus ligula odio, porta in libero non, ultrices mollis purus. Duis sollicitudin aliquet nunc, ut dictum turpis laoreet eget. Phasellus eu neque efficitur, bibendum odio vitae, sagittis libero. Proin commodo efficitur magna ac sollicitudin. Aenean bibendum urna at diam accumsan tincidunt. Proin ac elit vitae augue rutrum convallis. Donec magna ex, tempor at libero quis, mattis pharetra nunc. Maecenas sit amet nisi in odio interdum interdum.</p>
                </div><!-- .row -->
            </div><!-- .col-md-2 -->
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 site-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 info-bar">
                        <h2>SOME TITLE</h2>
                    </div><!-- .col-md-12 -->

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sem libero, vulputate vel tellus eu, suscipit facilisis metus. Nulla tempus cursus elit, eget pellentesque risus euismod ut. Fusce sed sodales mauris. In velit arcu, blandit sed tempor vitae, feugiat eu erat. Phasellus ligula odio, porta in libero non, ultrices mollis purus. Duis sollicitudin aliquet nunc, ut dictum turpis laoreet eget. Phasellus eu neque efficitur, bibendum odio vitae, sagittis libero. Proin commodo efficitur magna ac sollicitudin. Aenean bibendum urna at diam accumsan tincidunt. Proin ac elit vitae augue rutrum convallis. Donec magna ex, tempor at libero quis, mattis pharetra nunc. Maecenas sit amet nisi in odio interdum interdum.</p>

                        <p>Quisque ligula ex, pellentesque sit amet ligula non, ullamcorper egestas nulla. Sed in sapien ut velit finibus scelerisque ac quis purus. Etiam libero nibh, euismod id augue quis, condimentum aliquam diam. Integer faucibus vitae velit sed iaculis. Praesent laoreet neque est, at pharetra nunc scelerisque sit amet. Curabitur fringilla ex a quam commodo, quis hendrerit ipsum ullamcorper. Vestibulum pretium leo odio, feugiat tristique augue laoreet id. Aenean lobortis, mi sit amet pellentesque condimentum, lectus velit gravida diam, a consequat arcu magna eget diam. Phasellus in iaculis dolor, nec rhoncus dolor.</p>
                    </div><!-- .col-md-6 -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="article-photo">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x350" class="img-responsive" alt="article" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- .row -->
            </div><!-- .col-md-10 -->
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .container-fluid -->
</body>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xb6k5vth/).

I would like the title bar and sidebar to stay where they are and not scroll with the content. The only thing I want scrolling is the content (in blue).

How can I achieve this purely with CSS in Bootstrap?

Comment: Do you mean you want the sidebar and title bar to stick to the top and the content to scroll under it?

Comment: @Press, yes, if by under it you mean, under the title bar and to the side of the sidebar, basically, the blue section to scroll up and down and everything else to remain where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that top section is to be part of a dynamic page I would read about the Bootstrap Navbar (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). A very powerful tool that will be more dynamic than simple scroll styling for your page.

For a simple answer to your current fiddle you'll need to set the scroll to overflow and set a fixed height on the div(s) that you want to scroll. Adding these css attributes to the scrolling divs does what you describe.

```
style="overflow: scroll; max-height: 100px"
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xb6k5vth/1/